# Is there any way to set a token for more than one http request?

Tags: http, http-headers, node-red

I'm new using Node-Red and I do a HTTP request successfully with a bearer authentication token in the HTTP request function but it set only for these request. 
I want to put in the same flow page more request and all of them with the same token, how can I do that? Because I saw the http request node but it set token only for these request.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a change-node to set headers, you can then include that change node in a subflow, which you can then reuse before each http-request node.